# Angular 2 - IE 11 - Rendering of data is slow when compared to Chrome

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, shim

I have included the following files in my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- Website CSS -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/primeui-ng-all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tables.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/forms.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/portlets.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/plugins.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="controls/cal2/dynCalendar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsinc/plugins/raty/doc/css/stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/functional.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/templates.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tracker/tracker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom-styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsinc/tinyMCE/skins/bswift2016/skin.min.css">-->
    <!-- End Website CSS -- >

    <!-- Angular App Developer Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/primeui-ng-all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/tables.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/forms.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/portlets.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/plugins.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/dyncalendar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/responsive.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/functional.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/templates.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/tracker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/custom-styles.css">
    <!-- End Angular App Developer Css -->
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/plugins/tinymce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/jquery.MultiFile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsinc/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsinc/Notification/classie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsinc/Notification/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsinc/Notification/notificationFX.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/service/SessionService.js"></script>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/NotificationStyles/ns-default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/NotificationStyles/ns-style-attached.css" />
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        System.config({
            packages: {
                "app": {
                    format: 'cjs',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
                "components": {
                    format: 'cjs',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="tracker ad tracker-issue_search">
    <my-app>
    </my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

After adding shims_for_IE.js, the rendering of data in IE is too slow (we have to wait for some 30 seconds to see the data in page) when compared to Chrome. If I don't wait for the data to load, and click somewhere else on the page, whoosh...! the data loads perfectly.

Any idea/insights on this issue would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.